# How to add external js file in angular 6 library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I am creating an angular library (version 6) which is based on angular material for which I need to include the hammer js library.

I know that in angular 6 we can add the external js library in the `angular.json` under the project's configuration. But this does not work in case of above library. I tried to add the external library in the following way.

```
"my-library": {
  "root": "projects/my-library",
  "sourceRoot": "projects/my-library/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "projects/my-library/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "projects/my-library/ng-package.json",
        "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error.

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>     Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(scripts).

Please suggest what is the correct way to add external js file in the angular library.

Comment: You either have a typo somewhere in your actual code, or this is a bug, and you should file a bug report with the angular cli. There is nothing wrong with the code you just posted

Comment: This could be useful: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Comment: @nikhil have you found a solution for this? I am in a similar situation and import * or require do not work.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, have you got any luck on this , how to include scripts in angular library.

Answer (score 2):

So here are two possible problems we need to address

1) How to add the reference of external JS in the main angular project(demo project)

2) How to add the reference of external JS in NPM package.

**The solution for the 1'st scenario is :**

Provide the reference of your external JS in your `angular.json` file of main angular project in a script tag and provide the path of your package from your libraries node_modules folder like this.

`"scripts": [ "./projects/my-cool-library/node_modules/my-exteranl-library/dist/x.js"]`

**The solution for the 2'nd scenario is :**

**Approach 1**

So now you have created the NPM package from your library and you are going to use it in different project. obviously your 3rd party package dependency will get auto downloaded once you download your package you just have to provide the reference of that JS in script tag of `angular.json` file of new project.

`"scripts": [ "./node_modules/my-exteranl-library/dist/x.js"]`

**Approach 2**

Don't specify your third party dependency while creating your NPM package
remove the entry from `package.json` file of your cool-library

`"dependencies": {
    "my-exteranl-library": "^1.1.0"   <-- Remove this
  }`

and add the js directly in newly created application via CDN in index.html file using script tag

`<script src="https://demo-cdn.com/ajax/libs/my-exteranl-library/dist/x.js"></script>`

**There is 3rd way very you can download the JS by writing the code in your library will share here shortly.**

Comment: "will share here shortly", by the end of 2021 we're still waiting :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add your external library in the **tsconfig.lib.jso**n file.

Open that file and add your desires library under **types** node that you can find in **compilerOptios**. I give you and example. In my case I referenced the library from my project node module. You can do the same with your hammer.js library. Good luck

[image: using types to configure external js file]

Comment: Unable to add custom js file with this approach

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the OP's specific example trying to add hammer.js.  Just npm install hammerjs then edit your main.ts file and add `import 'hammerjs'` then it will be available globally.

Also see [this](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-5-gesture-support) article.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below command if you have used angular version 1.x before. And it works for me.

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

Comment: Already did this. But still getting the same error. I am using angular/cli version 6.0.8

Comment: Hi @nikhil, I update the answer. Please try this way.

Answer (score 0):

first add the libbrary in index.html or in

```
"scripts": [
"node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
]
```

> npm install d3 --save
>
> npm install @types/d3 --save-dev

If the library doesn't have typings available at @types/, you can still use it by manually adding typings for it:

1. First, create a `typings.d.ts` file in your `src/` folder. This file will be automatically included as global type definition.
2. Then, in `src/typings.d.ts`, add the following code:

   ```
   declare module 'typeless-package';
   ```
3. Finally, in the component or file that uses the library, add the following code:

   ```
   import * as typelessPackage from 'typeless-package';

   typelessPackage.method();
   ```

please follow the  [link](https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/1644)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, that's the behavior of `ng-packagr`, you'll get that error every time you try to add assets to a Library.
check this discussion for possible solution : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11071

Answer (score 0):

There two possible ways to solve this problem:

1) In your library specify `@angular/material` and `hammerjs` as **peer dependencies** so that all the applications that will use your library are required to provide the library themselves (this means that each app will have it's own `angular.json` with the `scripts` property containing the `hammerjs` js file)

2) Use [`ng-cli-packagr-tasks`](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ng-cli-packagr-tasks) custom build steps to [copy](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ng-cli-packagr-tasks/tree/master/examples/copy-files-and-bump) a `hammen.min.js` file from `node_modules` to the dist of a library and use relative import in your code.

Let me explain step #2 more detailed:

you want to use some kind of relative import like `require('../dependencies/hammer.min.js')` but this will result an error because after the library is build, the `../dependencies/hammer.min.js` will lead to uncertain place. To make sure that each time not only your `.ts` files will be magically transpiled to `.js` files but also the static `.js` files will be copied to a certain directory of a `dist` output of a library, you use `ng-cli-packagr-tasks`. After the build phase the `ng-cli-packagr-tasks` will copy the files using `glob` so that after you install the library in your application, the static `.js` files will be bundled as well. This means that the import `import('../dependencies/hammer.min.js).then()` will always lead to the file you've provided by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To load js file externally from assets

create service file add file to the assets and write path in array.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";


    declare var document: any;
    @Injectable({
        providedIn:'root'
    })
    export class ScriptService {
      private scripts: any = {};

      constructor() {
        ScriptConstant.forEach((script: any) => {
          this.scripts[script.name] = {
            loaded: false,
            src: script.src
          };
        });
      }

      load(...scripts: string[]) {
        var promises: any[] = [];
        scripts.forEach(script => promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
        return Promise.all(promises);
      }
      loadAll() {
        var promises: any[] = [];
        ScriptConstant.forEach(script => {
          // promises.push(delay(1000));
          promises.push(this.loadScript(script.name));
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
      }

      loadScript(name: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          //resolve if already loaded
          if (this.scripts[name].loaded) {
            resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: "Already Loaded" });
          } else {
            //load script
            let script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
            if (script.readyState) {
              //IE
              script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (
                  script.readyState === "loaded" ||
                  script.readyState === "complete"
                ) {
                  script.onreadystatechange = null;
                  this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                  resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: "Loaded" });
                }
              };
            } else {
              //Others
              script.onload = () => {
                this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: "Loaded" });
              };
            }
            script.onerror = (error: any) =>
              resolve({ script: name, loaded: false, status: "Loaded" });
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    interface Scripts {
        name: string;
        src: string;
      }
      export const ScriptConstant: Scripts[] = [
        { name: "multislider", src: "assets/js/multislider.js" },

      ];
```

Inject this ScriptService wherever you need it and load js libs like this

```
this.script.load('multislider').then(data => {
    console.log('script loaded ', data);
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score -3):

remove `../` before path of node_modules

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
]
```

Comment: Does not work with this approach. Still getting the same error. It is not the path issue. It is basically the script property is not allowed in case of library configuration. It works fine for test application but not for library.

Comment: This answer may not solve the entire issue, but Krishna is right, I don't have the `../` prefix in my `angular.json` scripts section, and my app builds perfectly fine.

Comment: @ArnaudP is your app a library type?

Comment: @JosephKhella I am referrering to a library project yes, bootstrapped with angular-cli. So to be precise, the `projects/` directory contains both a `lib/` directory, and an `app/` one. Only `lib/` is meant to be released as a package, and `app/` is only used locally to test (eg. Cypress) the integration of `lib` in a bigger app. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: @ArnaudP it does thank u :) did you have to include hammer in your project (not library) package.json as well?

Comment: I believe it depends on how you want your dependencies to be resolved.

Me, I decided to declare `peerDependencies` only in the lib `package.json`, which means that anyone wanting to use this lib will have to install the dependencies themselves (so, in that project, the dependencies have to be declared in the app `package.json`)

Alternately, I believe you can declare `dependencies` directly in your lib `package.json`, and in that case, they will be resolved transitively. No need to add them to the app `package.json`.