# How to import an external script in my Angular library?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to export some business logic ts files of my Angular application into an Angular library. Unfortunately, I need to use a Javascript file to connect to a proprietary service build by other people, which is only available as a pure javascript file and requires jQuery. 
Without libraries (when I was using the script in my angular application), I solved this by adding these js files to the .angular.json under the "scripts" section.

The js file is huge so I could not consider the option to rewrite in typescript.

Is there some way to import and use a javascript file in my ng library?

Thanks
Karan

Comment: put in index.html

Comment: Sorry this is not relevant to my query.

Comment: @pc_coder, Sorry, but angular libraries do not have index.html. Thanks anyways

Comment: @KaranDeepSingh: Sorry I had pasted the wrong link. Dees that one help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53313401/1160794

Comment: @pc_coder, thanks for sharing this. I had looked at this post already. It does not seem to solve the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally solved my issue.
Turns out there is no way to add a javascript file to an Angular library since ng library does not support "script" tag.

There is one other way: i.e. you can publish your library without the javascript file dependency, and the client using it will have to do 2 things:

1. `npm install "your-library"`
2. Now add the dependent javascript file to  `scripts` tag in `angular.json` file.

Example in my case:

Run `npm install wps-ng`

And my Angular.json looks like this:

`"scripts": [ "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", "node_modules/wps-js-52-north/src/web/lib/wps-js-all.js" ]`

Unlike the other libraries, just a simple `npm install` is not sufficient, the client will just need to add their javascript file to scripts tag.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But 1) How does the client get the dependent JavaScript file? 2) Why is the path of the dependent file `node_modules/wps-js-52-north/src/web/lib/`?

Comment: how do you use that script in a module then?